# Navigation Menu Image

Tags: magento2, menu

I want to display image in my navigation menu.

I've tried changing it's structure by adding `div/li` after `ul`, but it's not working.

Best solution for me is to add new `div` around the subcategory's `ul` having **"submenu"** class, But it's affecting the **display:block** flow of it.

Also tried overriding **menu.js**, but no results..

so please suggest me how to do this..